# Angular 4 conditional ngClass navbar not working

Tags: angular, ng-class

I´m trying to make my navbar transparent but only on the homepage. But this code is puzzlingly only working on the false condition. "isHome" Boolean is updated via router.events.subscribe and working properly.
This is my first attempt on Angular 4.

```
<nav [ngClass]="{'navbar navbar-toggleable-md bg-primary fixed-top navbar-transparent': this.isHome, 'navbar navbar-toggleable-md bg-primary fixed-top': !this.isHome} ">
```

Comment: Have you tried to see the value of `isHome` from the template with `{{ isHome }}` to see if it's changing the value accordingly to the page you're in?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's read the [**ngClass' docs**](https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass#description) (especifically `object` part):

> Object - keys are CSS classes that get added when the expression given in the value evaluates to a truthy value, otherwise they are removed.

So, taking your case as example:

```
<nav [ngClass]="{
  'navbar navbar-toggleable-md bg-primary fixed-top navbar-transparent': this.isHome,
  'navbar navbar-toggleable-md bg-primary fixed-top': !this.isHome 
}">
```

It means that:

1. When "home" evaluates to true, the classes navbar, navbar-toggleable-md, bg-primary, fixed-top **and** navbar-transparent will be added.
2. Once "home" evaluates to false, the classes navbar, navbar-toggleable-md, bg-primary, fixed-top will be removed, because there's a condition to add these classes if `home` evaluates to `true`.

For a deep explanation I'd recommend you to check [issue#5763(comment)](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/5763#issuecomment-166114033).

---

That said, to solve your problem is pretty easy. You can do either this:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-toggleable-md bg-primary fixed-top"
     [class.navbar-transparent]="this.isHome">
```

Or:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-toggleable-md bg-primary fixed-top"
     [ngClass]="{ 'navbar-transparent': this.isHome }">
```

---

Also, it's worth to mention that even though it's possible to use `this.<property>` in template it isn't recommended. It can be simply broken in future releases since it isn't even documented.

Comment: Thanks!! Because I am just beginning to learn Angular, can you explain to me why my approach does not work?

Comment: @KrombopulosMichael you're welcome. I've edited my answer.

Comment: Thank you so much, your explanation is really good. I had completely misunderstood the concept so far.